# Check is string from array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple arrays and i wish to check if the string selcted by random from one array is in another array and if so show an image

I have globaly set plistarray1 and plistarray2 in the h file  and in the m file i have the following

The last block of code is what im strugling with i cant get an image to display based on the random string generated from plistarray.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];






NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"data" ofType:@"plist"];







if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] && [[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]  ) {

        self.text.text =@"Are you ready for this?";
    [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];





        NSDictionary *plistDict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray * plistArray1 = plistDict1[@"truth"];



        NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];

        self.plistArray = [[plistArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2] mutableCopy];

    }

    else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) {

        self.text.text =@"I hope you are feeling brave!";
        [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];




        NSDictionary *plistDict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSArray *plistArray3 = plistDict3[@"truth"] ;

        self.plistArray = [plistArray3 mutableCopy];


        NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


    }

    else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dareonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) {

        self.text.text =@"This could be interesting!";
        [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];



        NSDictionary *plistDict4 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSMutableArray *plistArray4 = plistDict4[@"dare"];

        self.plistArray = [plistArray4 mutableCopy];


        NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


    }
    else {
        self.text.text =@"Please turn on Truth or Dare";
        [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];



    }



        ////display random quote from array

    int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;
        NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


        self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
        [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];
        [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];

        //display truth or dare image
        if ([plistArray containsObject:plistArray1]) {
            // selectedString is from the truth array
            self.truthimage.hidden = NO;


        }
```

Comment: For better performance use NSSet instead of NSArray. containsObject: or member: can be used to check a object is present or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks if the `plistArray` contains `plistArray1` object, which it does not (initially, it contains every single object from `plistArray1`, but not the `plistArray1` object itself).

Your code should be checking for the presence of the text, like this:

```
// Obtain the random quote that you plan to display
NSString* toDisplay = self.plistArray[randV];
// Display the quote
self.text.text = toDisplay;
// Remove that quote from the plistArray
[self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];
[Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];
// Now's the fix: check plistArray1 for the toDisplay object
if ([plistArray1 containsObject:toDisplay]) {
    // selectedString is from the truth array
    self.truthimage.hidden = NO;
}
```

This code can be made more efficient if you replace `plistArray1` with a set, which would let you check containment in amortized constant, rather than linear, time.

**EDIT :** (in response to this comment: "The `plistArray1` is being brought back as `nil`")

This is because you have declared `plistArray1` as a local variable in your method, in addition to having an instance variable by the same name. Replace this line

```
NSArray * plistArray1 = plistDict1[@"truth"];
```

with this

```
plistArray1 = plistDict1[@"truth"];
```

to fix the problem.

Comment: I can see how this works and have implimented it but the if statment dose not get called ?

Comment: @user3246508 What do you mean "the if statement dose not get called" - the code does not reach the `if` statement, or the code reaches the `if` statement, but does not enter its body because its condition evaluates to `NO`?

Comment: The pslistarry1 is being brought back as nul hmm??

Comment: This must have somthing to do with the arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray call when i add the two arrays together.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from what I think your code is saying you are checking to see if one plistArray is within the other plistArray. You just want to check if a string is contained in the array. You are close. Try this:

```
if ([plistArray1 containsObject:self.text.text]) {
            // selectedString is from the truth array
            self.truthimage.hidden = NO;
}
```

It's hard to follow what you're doing because of some of the variable names. Consider choosing more descriptive names so it's easier to pick up on what is going on.

Comment: The plistarray1 is being returned as null so this wont fire. This has confused me now